# How to safely insert a jsonb into a table?

Tags: postgresql, json, prepared-statement

I wrote this prepared statement for inserting jsonb data into a table:

```
PREPARE posts_insert(jsonb) AS
  INSERT INTO posts(data) VALUES($1) RETURNING ID;
```

Though I'm concerned if this query has some kind of vulnerabilities. The json comes from the client side of my application, so it could basically contain anything. Is it dangerous to use jsonb (that comes from the user) within queries? What can I do to make it safe or more safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it dangerous to use jsonb (that comes from the user) within queries?

Not it's not dangerous because that JSON is essentially just `text` as it comes from the client, and you've protected yourself by using prepared statements. This `text` will be transparently fed to the internal function `jsonb_in`, and you'll be totally safe.